# Laravel Model default value relative time now() + 24h

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Model in Laravel where I want to set the default value to the time 24 hours from now.

This is how I create the table currently.

```
Schema::create('contact_credits', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('amount')->default(0);
        $table->unsignedInteger('amount_used')->default(0);
        $table->unsignedInteger('company_id');
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
        $table->dateTime('expires_at');//default value now + 24h
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I tried the following:

```
...->default(\DB::raw('DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)'));
```

But I keep getting errors when trying to migrate.
How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you can only use constant values as default values in MySQL with the exception of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Though, you cannot do expressions in a default value, so this is not useful for this case.

I ended up overriding the 'create'-method of my ContactCredit Model where I add the attribute and get the correct timestamp with Carbon. So for every instance that get's created, before it get's created it set's the attribute. See below.

```
class ContactCredit extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = ['amount', 'expires_at'];
    protected $dates = ['expires_at'];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Company');
    }

    public static function create(array $attributes)
    {
        $attributes['expires_at'] = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(24);
        return parent::create($attributes);
    }    
}
```